# Can I change the default '/soap11' route for the SOAP endpoint on a ServiceStack implementation

Tags: servicestack

I know I can manage the routes for the REST-ful interface operations by attributing the DTOs

```
[Route("/widgets", "GET, POST")]
[DataContract()]
public class GetWidgetsRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string OutletCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IList<Specification> WidgetsCaptured { get; set; }
}
```

but I have searched and experimented unsuccessfully at trying to affect the default /soap11 appendage to the endpoint for a given SOAP operation.

```
**POST /soap11 HTTP/1.1**
Host: localhost    
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: nnn
SOAPAction: GetItemsRequest
```

A broader question within the question is, what are my options and how to configure the different endpoint settings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [SOAP Support docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) for guidelines and limitations of using SOAP in ServiceStack.

Comment: I did... hence my post.  The docs are very high level in this regard, and somewhat terse, almost purposefully vague.    Hey, if it can't be done, so be it.  I just wanted to make sure that is the case and not continue on a wild goose chase.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Guillo I'm not seeing anything showing that you've read it, given that your Request DTO is called `GetWidgetsRequest` instead of the specific convention of `GetWidgets` Request DTO and `GetWidgetsResponse` Response DTO makes me think you haven't. The docs show all the customizations you can do, i.e. Customizing response with **DataContract** attributes and the XML namespace in `Config.WsdlServiceNamespace`, and being able to process a raw message with `IRequiresSoapMessage`, other than that you'd need to set any additional HTTP Headers inside the service implementation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying... trust me, I did read it, but now I realize I simply misread the naming convention for the request/response DTOs.  Configuring the namespace is just that, it is not getting me what I need which is to effect the address for the endpoint.  Maybe I am not explaining what I need very effectively, so I'll make sure I post again if I get to the state I am seeking.

Answer (score 0):

For a different SOAP path, eg ~/services, you can add your own servicestack plugin , that returns your own servicestack soap handler.

```
public class MySoapFeature : IPlugin 
{
    private static IHttpHandler GetHandlerForPathParts(string[] pathParts)
    {
        string str2 = string.Intern(pathParts[0].ToLower());
        if (pathParts.Length != 1) return null;
        if (str2 == "services")
        {
            return new MySoapHttpHandler();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public IHttpHandler ProcessRequest(string httpMethod, string pathInfo, string filePath)
    {
        char[] chrArray = new char[] { '/' };
        string[] strArrays = pathInfo.TrimStart(chrArray).Split(new char[] { '/' });
        if ((int)strArrays.Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return MySoapFeature.GetHandlerForPathParts(strArrays);
    }

    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.CatchAllHandlers.Add(this.ProcessRequest);
    }
}
```

Then implement this handler based on Soap11Handler or Soap12Handler

```
    public class MySoapHttpHandler : Soap11Handler, IHttpHandler
{
    public MySoapHttpHandler()
        : base((EndpointAttributes)((long)32768))
    {
    }

    public new void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
        {
            (new Soap11WsdlMetadataHandler()).Execute(context);
            return;
        }

        Message message = base.Send(null);
        context.Response.ContentType = base.GetSoapContentType(context.Request.ContentType);
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(context.Response.OutputStream))
        {
            message.WriteMessage(xmlWriter);
        }
    }


    public override void ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, string operationName)
    {
        if (httpReq.HttpMethod == "GET")
        {
            (new Soap11WsdlMetadataHandler()).Execute(httpReq, httpRes);
            return;
        }

        Message message = base.Send(null, httpReq, httpRes);
        httpRes.ContentType = base.GetSoapContentType(httpReq.ContentType);
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(httpRes.OutputStream))
        {
            message.WriteMessage(xmlWriter);
        }
    }
```

Then register your plugin in the servicestack apphost Configure()

```
Plugins.Add(new MySoapFeature());
```

Then create your Dto classes for the request and response.  Have "Response" added to the response dto class name.  Do NOT put a Route attribute on the request Dto, as it gets routed by the Soap method name in the Xml.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://mynamespace/schemas/blah/1.0")]
public class MySoapMethod
{}


DataContract(Namespace = "http://mynamespace/schemas/blah/1.0")]
public class MySoapMethodResponse
{
     [DataMember]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then have a Service to implement the Soap Dto's

```
public class SOAPService : Service
{
    public MySoapMethodResponse Post(MySoapMethod request)
    {
        var response = new MySoapMethodResponse();
        response.SomeProperty = "blah";
        return response;
    }
}
```